# Symfony: authenticate with API KEY doesn't keep sessions

Tags: api, symfony, authentication

As Symfony Manual I followed this steps http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html to enable the authentication via an external token provided in the URL.

When I pass the token in the URL Symfony do the login but if I change page I lose the session.

This is the code:

```
public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
{

    $targetUrl = '/myproject/login';
    if (!$this->httpUtils->checkRequestPath($request, $targetUrl)) {
        // DO REDIRECT
    }

    if (!$request->query->has('apikey')) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('No API key found');
    }

    return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
        'anon.',
        $request->query->get('apikey'),
        $providerKey
    );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be stateless?